# Slow writeback, but fast direct IO

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm trying to debug why writeback is slow on an AWS instance (AWS support is perplexed too). `cat /proc/meminfo | grep Dirty` reports ~200 MB that's pending to be written. This data is being written at an extremely slow pace of < 16 KB/s.

The most interesting thing here is that if I instruct `dd` to use direct IO (`oflag=direct`), I'm able to write to my disk at ~250 MB/s. However, `dd` without direct IO writes at ~16 KB/s.

Any pointers on what to look at next, given that direct IO is able to write data fast?